# How can I get the list of updates via command line in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Suppose there is some updation and addition of folder done by some developers in svn. Now next day I come and do the update via Tortoisesvn->right-click->update and get the result like:

[image]

It is a very less but in reality there are lots of files. Now I want to ask how can I get the same result via command-line. As when I update it with GUI and mistakenly click OK button then all info got disappear(right now I save the screenshot everytime) and I became empty handed.

Is there any command line which tells me exact output which I got via GUI.
I tried **svn log** command but it does not provide the info same as GUI update.

Comment: Can you describe why you need this list? IOW, what is your end goal - not the path you've chosen to get to it. There is probably a different (better) way to do what you think you need to be doing here.

Comment: Sure. Actually daily I need to syn the files and folders from the client side and for that I need that list.

Comment: Sync to where, and via what method? If you're trying to cherry-pick files to copy for deployment, you really don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**TortoiseSVN | Check for Modifications** dialog](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html#tsvn-dug-locking-dia-status). By default, the dialog shows your local modifications, however you can click **Check repository** button and it will show incoming changes from the repository.

Using Subversion command-line client, you can [run the command `svn status --show-updates`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/status/#Content_Content_Content_ctl00) that will show you which files will be updated if you run `svn update`.

Answer (score 0):

After you close that window, there is no way of getting a list of the files that were updated.

You can only capture a list of files that will be updated before the update is performed (by using `svn status --show-updates`), or a list of the files that were just updated at the time of the update (by saving, in whatever way you like, the output of `svn update`).

The working copy doesn't keep a history of where it was before each update, so unless *you* keep a record of which revision you're at after each update, the list of files updated when you run `svn update` is ephemeral.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, `svn update` does exactly the same thing as the "update" command in TortoiseSVN, and outputs the actions taken in textual form. But if you have already done an update, it won't show you the information again; that information is transient. So the command line won't help you.

However, TortoiseSVN keeps a log of command outputs, including update operations, which you can access at a later time if you do it soon enough afterwards. To see the log, and control how long it stores the data, go to TortoiseSVN→Settings→Saved Data and look at the "action log" section.